# Blue And Red Tint In MC 1.0

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Everything in Minecraft 1.0 is a blue and red tint.  Water is red tinted and everything else is blue tinted.

[image]

Here are some extra details:

- My 3d anaglyphic is off
- I am using a Macbook with the M1 chip

Screenshots:
[image: Loading Screen]

[image: Home Page]

[image: In Game]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you got 3d anaglyph enabled? Go into Options > Video Settings and if it's turned on, turn it off.

Comment: Could it be some sort of colorblind setting? I don't know if Minecraft has such settings, but if so, check those.

Comment: I have posted an answer to my own post, with extra details, if you need them please look at it

Comment: @Cryptye I turned your answer into an edit.  You can [edit your own post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/395129/edit) by clicking the edit button that should be under the tag.

Comment: Thank you timmy!

Answer (score 3):

I tested this on my Intel Mac, and Minecraft 1.0 works fine. After doing some research I found out that it is a M1 issue. Here's how to fix it:

First, download [this file](https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu8.60.0.21-ca-jre8.0.322-macosx_aarch64.zip) (or look for JRE 8 aarch64 on Azul Zulu).

Next, double-click it.

Then, in your launcher profile, change the Java executable to

> /Users/<username>/Downloads/zulu8.60.0.21-ca-jre8.0.322-macosx_aarch64/zulu-8.jre/Contents/Home/bin/java

### It should look like this

[image]

If that doesn't work, follow [these instructions](https://github.com/yusefnapora/m1-multimc-hack), but use my Azul Zulu JRE link, instead of the link provided by them.

Comment: hello, i downloaded the file and changed my executable but when pressing play i get this message:

"Unable to locate the Java runtime.
Error details: Undefined error: 0
Filename on disk: java
Path: /Users//Downloads/zulu8.60.0.21-ca-jre8.0.322-macosx_aarch64/zulu-8.jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
Exists: Nonexistent"

Comment: Change /Users// to /Users/YourUsername/.

Comment: Thank you @MrParrot. Its launching but its either a white or black screen. I reset all. my video settings in 1.18.1 but it still wont work

Comment: Click on the cross next to the Java executable to reset it. Try using MultiMC instead. Download MultiMC (from https://multimc.org), and follow these instructions (https://github.com/yusefnapora/m1-multimc-hack).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have super-secret settings enabled to one of the custom shaders. I am not completely aware of version 1.0, but it should be on the first page of the settings menu.

Comment: Super secret settings?

Comment: Those were added in 1.7

Comment: So if somebody activated them by mistake... how would someone turn them off? Adding that would make your answer a good one. Right now it just states the problem, but doesn't actually tell the asker how to actually fix it.

Comment: Super secret settings is always reset when starting the game. It also doesn't effect the title or loading screen.